# How do I use invoke-command to run a PS file from the windows command line while passing parameters to the PS file?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

How do I use invoke-command to run a PS file from the windows command line while passing parameters to the PS file?
This is my script:

```
#TestParams2.ps1

param (
    [string]$Server,
    [string]$FileFolderName,
    [string]$VerValue
)

$Server
$FileFolderName
$VerValue
```

And this is how I'm trying to call it:

```
powershell.exe invoke-command -FilePath 'C:\temp\TestParams2.ps1' -ArgumentList 'myserver','\\server1\folder name\file.txt','9999'
```

And when I run it, I get this:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ invoke-command -FilePath 'C:\temp\TestParams2.ps1' -ArgumentList 'mys ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

How should I call the script?

Comment: Looks like you have to specify a computer.

Answer (score 1):

[zdan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58720458/45375) contains the crucial pointer: **the `-FilePath` parameter is only meant to be used in the context of *remoting***, so you cannot use it unless you also specify the `-ComputerName` parameter.

However, using `-ComputerName` just so you can target the *local* machine is (a) inefficient and (b), more importantly, requires *running as admin* (elevated).

**You don't need `Invoke-Command` at all; instead, call your script with the `-File` CLI parameter**, passing the arguments as usual, separated with spaces:

```
powershell.exe -File C:\temp\TestParams2.ps1 myserver "\\server1\folder name\file.txt" 9999
```

If you also need to bypass the effective [execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies):

**Caveat**: If the effective execution policy is controlled by a *Group Policy*, it cannot be overridden.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\temp\TestParams2.ps1 myserver "\\server1\folder name\file.txt" 9999
```

Note that `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` must be placed *before* the `-File` parameter (applies analogously to use of the `-Command` parameter) - anything after `-File` is considered the target script path plus any arguments to pass through to it.

Comment: That works, but not when the script file is on a network share like this:
powershell.exe -File \\netserv01\Progs\temp\TestParams2.ps1 myserver "\\server1\folder name\file.txt" 9999

When I do that, it asks me for run confirmation.  How do I avoid that?
I've tried using the unblock-file command and I've tried -ExecutionPolicy Bypass and neither worked.

Comment: @cashonly: Be sure to place `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` _before_ the `-File` parameter. If that doesn't help, your execution policy is likely controlled by a _Group Policy_, which means that you cannot override it this way. If that is the case, your only option is to ask that the Group Policy be changed - please see my  update.

Answer (score 0):

The error is complaining that the set of parameters that you supplied to `invoke-command` is not complete such that it could not resolve which parameter set to `invoke-command` to apply.

In this case, when you specify the `-FilePath` argument, you must supply `-ComputerName` as well:

```
powershell.exe invoke-command -FilePath 'C:\temp\TestParams2.ps1' -ArgumentList 'myserver','\\server1\folder name\file.txt','9999' -ComputerName localhost
```

Comment: Well done on spotting the root cause. However, using `-ComputerName` just so you can target the _local_ machine is (a) inefficient and (b), more importantly, requires _running as admin_ (elevated).

Comment: @mklement0 agree with point (a). As for (b), I can run this without elevating. Do you have a reference?

Comment: I get an `Access denied` error when I run the following from `cmd.exe` in a non-elevated session: `powershell.exe icm -computername localhost { hostname }`. What do you get?

Comment: @mklement0 I get my hostname.

Comment: Perhaps you have UAC turned off / are running from an already-elevated session?

Comment: As for a reference: "On Windows Vista and later versions of the Windows operating system, to include the local computer in the value of ComputerName, you must run PowerShell using the Run as administrator option." - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command?view=powershell-7

Comment: UAC is not turned off. My logged on account is not and admin account and I did not elevate the command prompt. But I do have remoting turned on. Perhaps that's it.

Comment: Remoting _must_ be turned on for the command to have any chance of succeeding at all - but only _with elevation_, from my experience (and as indicated in the docs).